# align li tag styled with css

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand why my li is floating like this:

[image: Bullet]

When I look at the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zzor1m0b/) they are aligned fine. Can anybody see what is wrong?

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(section);
  counter-increment: section;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
**Updated code to question**
```

```html
<div id="feature">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 text-center feature-title">

                    <!-- Seminariet bulletpoints -->
                    <h2>PÅ BAGGRUND AF SEMINARIET VIL DU</h2>
                    
                        <ul>
                            <li>First item</li>
                            <li>Second item</li>
                            <li>Third item</li>
                        </ul>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

**Updated picture**

[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

Comment: The code you posted in your question seems fine. Please revise it to include a [mcve]

Comment: Please try including your ul inside a parent div.

Comment: Perhaps the block, the ul is in, has a `text-align: center` or something?

Comment: agree with @TimVermaelen on this. Definitely that is the reason.

Comment: Gggrrr yes text-align in the block was set to center. Thank you a lot for the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess the problem is that you have `text-align:center` on the `li` or on the `ul` ( as far as i can see from your screenshot, in your code everything is fine )

so you want to center the `li`s . they stay like that because every `li` has a different text length so they align correctly on the center of their parent `ul`

there are a number of ways to make them aligned on center and also nicely one on top of the other. this would be one of the solutions

**EDIT** centering `ul` the way you want it to look ( without `text-align:center` ) it's problematic so you need to use something like the snippet below

i think it will be much more responsive. if not, you can always use `@media query` to make it ' look good ' on smaller devices

( also made some example @media Queries )

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;

    padding:0;
    left:45%;
    display:inline-block;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  line-height: 40px;



}
li:before {
  content: counter(section);
  counter-increment: section;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 
 
}
h2 { 
text-align:center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
ul {
  left:40%;
}

}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
ul {
  left:35%;
}

}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
ul {
  left:25%;
}

}
```

```html
<div id="feature">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12 text-center feature-title">

                    <!-- Seminariet bulletpoints -->
                    <h2>PÅ BAGGRUND AF SEMINARIET VIL DU</h2>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        <ul style="text-align:left">
                            <li>First item</li>
                            <li>Second item</li>
                            <li>Third item</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, and that was the solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: But I just came to think of. If I want to center the h2 tag, but also align the 3 bullets point, so they are under the centered h2 tags. How can I do that?

Comment: which are the h2 tags ? can't see anything except `ul` and `li` in your html structure :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I just updated my question with all the code the question is about. I would like that the h2 tag is centered and also the ul is centered under aswell, but they should be on a nice line. If I use padding or margin for that, it looks horrible on a mobile. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: edited my answer. i guess it's the best solution in terms of responsiveness . but you can always use @media to change the `left:40%`  of the `ul`. let me know if it does the trick . also...do not forget to rate the answer as the accepted one :) thanks !

Comment: Thank you a lot again. It is so close that it is like I want it. I just do not understand why they are flying to the right on my screen. I cannot upload a picture to my question for some reason, but I made an upload here: https://postimg.org/image/5z1vq5h97/ I hope you can help me with the last here.